# Beamer Rmarkdown: no page number for specific slides

Tags: r-markdown, beamer

I have some slides produced in Rmarkdown. I just want the slides after the conclusion not to have numbers. I tried all the solutions that are posted in this website and similar (e.g.: *\appendix
\setcounter{framenumber}{2}*, *\pagenumbering{gobble}*, etc.) but they don't work. Also this [Rbeamer for back-up slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228938/beamer-rmarkdown-changing-slide-count-for-backup-slides) doesn't work in my case and I don't understand why.

This is my framework:

```
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
date: "xx/xx/2020"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "Boadilla"
    colortheme: "orchid"

header-includes:
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc,tikzmark}
- \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,shapes.geometric}
- \usepackage{lipsum}
- \usepackage{lmodern}
- \usepackage{tcolorbox}
- \usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

---
## Title 1

Text 1

---

## Title 2

Text 2

---

## Conclusion

concluding 

---

## NO PAGE NUMBER

I don't want page numbers here
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beamer Rmarkdown, changing slide count for backup slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228938/beamer-rmarkdown-changing-slide-count-for-backup-slides)

Comment: @samcarter no unfortunately, I saw it before but it doesn't work in my case, I don't know why